# Receiving null values in REST Resource

Tags: java, json, rest, post, jersey

I keep receiving null values while sending these two parameters thru a POST with ajax (tried with Poster as well):

```
@POST
@Path("/update")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void update(String Path, String Content) {

updateURI(Path,Content);


    }
```

Path: http://essam.ldm.io/stor...amblog/ChannelList/ch1/post2

Content: `<http://essam.ldm.io/storage/essamblog/ChannelList/ch1/post2> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://crosscloud/mblog/Post>. <http://essam.ldm.io/storage/essamblog/ChannelList/ch1/post2> <http://crosscloud/mblog/owner> <https://essam.ldm.io></https:>. <http://essam.ldm.io/storage/essamblog/ChannelList/ch1/post2> <http://purl.org/dc/terms/created> <2013-03-06T16:41:18+0300^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime>. <http://essam.ldm.io/storage/essamblog/ChannelList/ch1/post2> <http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#content>.`

Obviously I cannot send them as `@QueryParam` or `@PathParam` due to the format.

It is irrilevant putting the jQuery code since it deosnt wotk with Poster neither, but here it is:

```
function doUpdate(path, rdf)
        {
            var obj1 = {"path": path, "rdf": rdf};
            var sUrl = "http://localhost:8080/browsing/services/RDF/update";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: sUrl,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: obj1,
                //dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (resp, status, xhr) {
                   $("#message").html("STATUS: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + "\n" + resp);
                   $("#message").hide();
                   $("#login_message").html("<font color='green'><b>Record succesfully updated</b></font>d");
                },
                error: function(resp, status, xhr){
                    $("#message").html("ERROR: " + resp.status + " " + resp.statusText + "\n" + xhr);
                    $("#message").show();
                }
            });
        }
```

Anything I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode it (i.e. base64) before you send it and decode it on server or you can use JSON as request param.

Using JSON, for example;

```
@POST
@Path("/update")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void update(PathContext ctx) {
    updateURI(ctx.getPath(),ctx.getContent());
}

@XmlRootElement
public class PathContext {
    private String path;
    private String content;

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

Your JSON will look like;

```
{"path": somePath, "content": someContent}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Trying now to create an XmlRootEelement like you suggested, but encoding I tried with "var sRdf = encodeURIComponent(rdf)" but it changes some tags in it in quotes..etc.

Comment: If you want to use encoding, go with base64. http://scotch.io/quick-tips/js/how-to-encode-and-decode-strings-with-base64-in-javascript

Comment: Encoding works but I get 400 Bad Request and tells me that "The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method."

Comment: If you are using encoding then do not use @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), just add @QueryParam to your method signature. Upper solution is with JSON, but both of them should work.

Comment: the @Consumes works, in fact along with '{"path": "", "rdf": ""}' is what made it fire from Poster and also from my JQuery. Now putting actual parameters instead of String as values gives me 400 Bad request error. So I would consider this Solved and open another once for this JSON formatting issue.

Comment: Composing the JSON as follows and stringhifying it solved it!

var data = {"path": path, "rdf": encodedRdf}; and 
data: JSON.stringify(data),